# How can i generate narrative Tableau dashboard?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, tableau-api, nlg

I have a Tableau BI dashboard on which i want to generate Narrative Insights. My Data does not have relevant text for generating new sentences. How can i go about it?

I am quite comfortable in python but I am unable to make out how to go about it?

Comment: Try the Python integration that is available for Tableau.

Comment: I researched and got to know this thing comes under NLG which I have no idea of. Can you help?

Comment: you can research for the same or take the help of your Tableau account relationship manager to better help you out on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on package for data2text, called narrator. It is a template-based NLG framework, currently can be installed from github.
[narrator](https://denisabd.github.io/narrator/)

Currently there are two types of narratives - **descriptive** and **trend**

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("denisabd/narrator")
```

Here are some example outputs

```
library(narrator)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)

sales %>%
  narrate_descriptive(
    measure = "Sales",
    dimensions = c("Region", "Product"))
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzF0C.png)